# Ruby on Rails Tutorial chapter 9.3.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried to do chapter 9.3.3 in Ruby on Rails Tutorial (http://railstutorial.org).

Whenever I run the tests it say something along the lines of:

```
Failures:

  1) Users sign in/out success should sign a user in and out
     Failure/Error: user = Factory(:user)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:53:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 5.8 seconds
4 examples, 1 failure
```

I've tried various fixes including resetting the database - both using rake db:reset and rake db:populate.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you run rake db:reset and then open up the database in an SQL Browsing program to confirm that the data definitely isn't there, and there isn't a conflict between production / development / testing databases?

Comment: one thing that comes to mind is that the rake db tasks by default target your development db, not the test db. If you add a break point (gem install 'ruby-debug19' gets you a semi-decent debugger) you can inspect the test database from the debugger and see what is really there at the time of test execution.

Comment: How do I add a break point? I installed the gem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your test database is not wrapped around a transaction while your tests are running. This is causing you test database to persist between test runs. Use [database cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) to clean up your test database after each spec is run.

Comment: That did not work - it still display the same errors even though I put it into all relevant files I'm aware of.